# Is there a parallelizable algorithm for training sparse neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

Consider that we want to create a very big neural network. If we consider to use dense layers, we might face some challenges. Now consider that we use sparse layers instead of dense layers. When using a really sparse model, we would have much less parameters and could create much bigger neural networks. Is there an efficient algorithm to parallelize the training of such networks?